# how to pass ID value from one page to another

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have three hyperlinks in my table.
These hyperlinks are used for the print preview of the crystal reports.
The problem is the selected content of the print preview of the crystal report should be equal to the ID from the other page.

here is the code behind, this page will be responsible for the passing and redirecting of the ID

```
    Sub OnFinishButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles Wizard1.FinishButtonClick
    If Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = 6 Then
        ''au1.regau1()
    ElseIf Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = 7 Then
        'au2.regau2()
    End If
    Response.Redirect("~/operator/renewInstruction.aspx")
End Sub
```

and this is the other page.
Here is my hyperlink in table:

```
<table class="req">
  <tr class="field_value3">
     <td><asp:Label ID="req3" runat="server" Text="A. Affidavit of Undertaking(FVO shall comply with the requirements of R.A. 8550)" ></asp:Label></td><td>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="au8550_h4" runat="server" ForeColor ="blue" Target="_Blank"><asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl ="~/images/preview.png" Height="25px" Width="30px" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"/></asp:HyperLink></td>
  </tr> 
     <tr class="field_value4">
     <td><asp:Label ID="req4" runat="server" Text="B. Affidavit of Undertaking to the effect that the FVO shall comply with FAQ No. 232 (applicable only to fishing vessels which intend to operate in Manila Bay)" ></asp:Label></td><td>
     <asp:Hyperlink ID="au232_h3" runat="server" Target="_blank" ForeColor ="Blue" ><asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl ="~/images/preview.png" Height="25px" Width="30px" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"/></asp:Hyperlink></td>
  </tr> 
    <tr class="field_value5">
    <td><asp:Label ID="req5" runat="server" Text="C. Certification to the effect that the fishing vessel is not involved in any administrative or judicial case" ></asp:Label></td><td>
    <asp:HyperLink  ID="Cert_h5" runat="server" Target ="_blank" ForeColor ="blue"><asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" ImageUrl ="~/images/preview.png" Height="25px" Width="30px" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"/></asp:HyperLink></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

here is the code behind for the hyperlink:

```
au232_h3.NavigateUrl = "~/operator/printAU232.aspx?Au232VesselID=" & Session("vid")
            au8550_h4.NavigateUrl = "~/operator/printAu8550.aspx?Au8550VesselID=" & Session("vid")
            Cert_h5.NavigateUrl = "~/operator/printCERT.aspx?CertVesselID=" & Session("vid")
```

how will i able to pass the value of vid to the other page so that it will be the unique basis for the selection of the print preview content of the crystal report.

Comment: in what page lifecycle does the last snippet shared above execute - page load or some button click?

Comment: Are you not already passing `Session("vid")` in the querystring? If so you can retrieve it on the next page using Request.Querystring["vid"]

Comment: there is a button from the other page, once clicked it will redirect to the other page.. the id which is the vid should be passed during the redirect page ..